# ActiveRecord distinct doesn't work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I made a Select using Active Record with a lot of Joins. This resulted in duplicate values. After the *select* function there's the *distinct* function with value :id. But that didn't work!

Here's the code:

```
def join_query
  <<-SQL
    LEFT JOIN orders on orders.purchase_id = purchases.id
    LEFT JOIN products on products.id = orders.complete_product_id
  SQL
end

def select_query
  <<-SQL
    purchases.*,
    products.reference_code as products_reference_code
  SQL
end

result = Purchase.joins(join_query)
                 .select(select_query)
                 .distinct(:id)
```

Of course, neither *distinct!* or *uniq* functions worked. The *distinct!* returned a error from "ActiveRecord::ImmutableRelation" that I don't know what means.

To fix this I did a hack, converting the ActiveRecord_Relation object to an Array and I used the *uniq* function of Ruby.

What's going on here?

Comment: `ImmutableRelation` means that ActiveRecord [has already fetched the query](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ImmutableRelation.html). Try putting your `joins` at the end.

Comment: What RDBMS you are using? What you see if you don't use `.distinct(:id)` ? I doubt use of `.distinct(:id)` is the problem, because it is trying to select records, which are fetched.

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

```
def select_query
  <<-SQL
    DISTINCT ON (purchases.id) purchases.id,
    products.reference_code as products_reference_code
  SQL
end

add more comma separated column names in select clause

Purchase.select(select_query).joins(join_query)
```